# jQuery code behaves differently in Debug vs. Release mode

Tags: asp.net, jquery, compilation, release

I am developing a website where I am using a tabs implementation with jQuery. In Debug mode, all runs fine, I spent the entire day developing it, and when I was about to deploy to the live site and I compiled in 'Release' mode, the tabs don't switch anymore. Why would this code behave differently? I am assuming it's the JavaScript code that gets executed differently.

Any ideas of what I could check? Thanks.

Comment: I'm 99% sure that it's not javascript. At least i can't figure out any reason why it could act differently when asp.net app is build in release mode.

Answer (score 1):

You might try using [Javascript Lint](http://www.javascriptlint.com/) to check your Debug code for the type of errors mentioned in btelles' answer.  You'll have to stick a `/*jsl:ignore*/` tag around the jQuery library itself if you end up using it though, as the it has a bunch of stuff that is caught by Lint.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tip, Wesley but apparently something else got broken in the process and it now fails in Debug mode too. The problem must be somewhere else. Still digging.

Comment: Tip=>use comments to add comments instead of answers. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your paths?
Go to the viewsource of the page and check if jquery path is valid.

cheers